# Unprocessed time in java game loop

Tags: java, game-loop

I was looking at notch's game loop and i can't understand what is the meaning of unprocessedTime variable.

```
long now = System.nanoTime();
unprocessedTime += now - lastTime;
lastTime = now;
```

I would be really grateful if someone could explain me the difference between the two variables.Thanks

```
public void run() {
    requestFocus();
    Image image = new BufferedImage(320, 240, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    setScreen(new TitleScreen(this));

    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    long unprocessedTime = 0;

   [b] try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }[/b]

    while (running) {
        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();

        long now = System.nanoTime();
        unprocessedTime += now - lastTime;
        lastTime = now;

        int max = 10;
        [b]while (unprocessedTime > 0) {
            unprocessedTime -= 1000000000 / 60;
            fps = unprocessedTime;
            screen.update(input);
            input.update();
            if (max-- == 0) {
                unprocessedTime = 0;
                break;
            }
        }[/b]
        screen.render(g);
        g.dispose();

        try {
            started = true;
            g = getGraphics();
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, GAME_WIDTH * SCREEN_SCALE, GAME_HEIGHT * SCREEN_SCALE, 0, 0, GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT, null);
            g.dispose();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the full code, but it seems to be the total time for all the loops.

Answer (score 0):

This is accumnulating the lapsed time in nanoseconds between the last time the event was triggered...

According to Java Doc (if you need to know about [nanoTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()))
    System.nanoTime();

> Returns the current value of the most precise available system timer,
>   in nanoseconds. This method can only be used to measure elapsed time
>   and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time.
>   The value returned represents nanoseconds since some fixed but
>   arbitrary time (perhaps in the future, so values may be negative).
>   This method provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily
>   nanosecond accuracy. No guarantees are made about how frequently
>   values change. Differences in successive calls that span greater than
>   approximately 292 years (263 nanoseconds) will not accurately compute
>   elapsed time due to numerical overflow.